# EF Mock of dbContext dont use eager loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I try to use NUnit and Moq to unit test a service, which access data. I create Mock of DbContext like this:

My entities and context

```
 public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Test method:

```
public void CreateBlog_saves_a_blog_via_context()
    {
       var data = new List<Blog>
        {
            new Blog { Name = "BBB" },
            new Blog { Name = "ZZZ" },
            new Blog { Name = "AAA" },
        }.AsQueryable();

        var data2 = new List<Blog>
        {
            new Post{ Title= "BBB" },
            new Post{ Title= "ZZZ" },
            new Post{ Title= "AAA" },
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockSet2 = new Mock<DbSet<POs>>();
        mockSet2.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data2.Provider);
        mockSet2.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data2.Expression);
        mockSet2.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data2.ElementType);
        mockSet2.As<IQueryable<Post>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data2.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Posts).Returns(mockSet2.Object);
        var service = new BlogService(mockContext.Object);
        var blogs = service.GetAllBlogs();
    }
```

But when I wont to set relational between entities I test them

```
Post = new Post(){
  Title ="",
  Content = "",
  BlogID = 2
};
```

But navigation property don't set in the test(In the normal setup its setups). When I try to read this post from context I always have null, but BlogID is already set.

Comment: I think you have a copy paste mistake    ar data2 = new List<Blog>
should be Post correct?

Comment: You have to set in the Blog collection             new Blog { Name = "BBB" , Posts = new List() { new Post{ Title= "BBB" },.....
} },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would unit test this a different way, looking at the name of your unit test you are simply trying to ensure that when a blog is created, the correct data is passed into the DbContext.. you can do this as follows;

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void CreateBlog_saves_a_blog_via_context()
    {
        var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>();

        // Add related posts directly into fake blog data
        var data = new List<Blog>
        {
            new Blog {Name = "BBB", Posts = new List<Post>() { new Post() { Title = "Post1"} } },
            new Blog {Name = "ZZZ", Posts = new List<Post>() { new Post() { Title = "Post2"} } },
            new Blog {Name = "AAA", Posts = new List<Post>() { new Post() { Title = "Post3"} } },
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        var service = new BlogService(mockContext.Object);

        var newBlog = new Blog {Name = "A New Blog", Posts = new List<Post>() {new Post() {Title = "Post1"}}};

        // Add new Blog to service
        service.AddBlog(newBlog);

        // Check that DbContext received the new blog correctly
        // And Blog contained correct name and Post count of 1
        mockSet.Verify(x=>x.Add(It.Is<Blog>(blog=>blog.Name == "A New Blog" && blog.Posts.Count == 1)));
    }
```

As I hope you can see, you are ensuring that your class under test is passing the correct object to the DbContext correctly. You could now also make additional assertions, such as confirmation that the SaveChanges() method in the DbContext has also been called only once.

Test your class, not the DbContext

Comment: Oh thank you, I got it earlier but I`ll like you for your job. Have a nice day!